# Site stops working after few seconds with IIS Express

Tags: c#, wpf, iis-express

I have to start the IIS Express from a WPF Application. I can start IISExpress, and browser on the website for a few seconds. Then when I click any link it doesn't load. Then If I close the WPF Application the webpage responds immediately. My code:

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   StartSite();
}

public void StartSite()
{
    string path = @"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe";
    string args = @"/path:C:\Sites /port:9090 /systray:true";

   if (!File.Exists(path))
      throw new FileNotFoundException();

   var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
   {
     FileName = path,
     Arguments = args,
     RedirectStandardOutput = true,
     UseShellExecute = false,
     CreateNoWindow = true
   });
}
```

Any guesses why the website works for just few seconds and will work again after closing the application that launched iisexpress?

**Edit**

I notice that when I build in "Debug" it happens, but when I build in "Release" the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: First IIS Express is not designed for you to bundle in your app. Second, attach a debugger such as WinDbg to the process and you can easily see why it ends. You might also launch it with trace enabled to get more info from itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating an IIS Launcher(console application). I pass some arguments to this application, it starts IISExpress then dies. Now in my WPF application instead of creating a process for IISExpress, I create a process for my launcher. Also this console application returns the process id to WPF through exit code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args == null)
            Environment.Exit(-1);

        string exeIIS = args[0];
        string websitePath = args[1];
        string port = args[2];

        string argsIIS = MakeIISExpressArgs(websitePath, port);
        int processID = LaunchIISExpress(argsIIS, exeIIS);

        Environment.Exit(processID);
    }

    private static int LaunchIISExpress(string argsIIS, string pathExeIIS)
    {
        var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = pathExeIIS,
            Arguments = argsIIS,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        });

        return process.Id;
    }

    private static string MakeIISExpressArgs(string websitePath, string port)
    {
        var argsIIS = new StringBuilder();
        argsIIS.Append(@"/path:" + websitePath);
        argsIIS.Append(@" /Port:" + port);
        return argsIIS.ToString();
    }

}
```